# Convert string to binary

Tags: objective-c, json

I receive a response from web service as json string and I want it to convert that string to binary.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *binary*? in one sense all computer data is 1s and 0s ... hmm ... maybe you mean some *other* binary representation?

Answer (score 0):

```
char s[255] = "JSON String value";
//for each character, print it's binary aoutput
int i,c,power;
for ( i=0 ; s[i]!='\0' ; i++ )
 {
  //c holds the character being converted
  c = s[i];
  //for each binary value below 256 (because ascii values < 256)
  for ( power=7 ; power+1 ; power-- )
  //if c is greater than or equal to it, it is a 1
  if ( c >= (1<<power) )
   {
     c -= (1<<power); //subtract that binary value
     printf("1");
   }
   //otherwise, it is a zero
  else
     printf("0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use dataUsingEnconding message from the NSString object:

[dataUsingEncoding:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/dataUsingEncoding%3a)